# How to set class to all text node parents inside of specific block

Tags: php, domdocument

I need to set a class to parent of each text node inside of specific block on my page.

Here is what I'm trying to do:

```
$pageHTML = '<html><head></head>
<body>

<header>
  <div>
    <nav>Menu</nav>
    <span>Another text</span>
  </div>
</header>

<section>Section</section>
<footer>Footer</footer>
</body>
</html>';

$dom = new DOMDocument;
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom->loadHTML($pageHTML);
libxml_use_internal_errors(false);

foreach($dom->getElementsByTagName('body')[0]->childNodes as $bodyChild) {

    if($bodyChild->nodeName == 'header') {

        $blockDoc = new DOMDocument();
        $blockDoc->appendChild($blockDoc->importNode($bodyChild, true));
        $xpath = new DOMXpath($blockDoc);

        foreach($xpath->query('//text()') as $textnode) {
            if(preg_match('/\S/', $textnode->nodeValue)) { // exclude non-characters
                 $textnode->parentNode->setAttribute('class','my_class');
            }
        }
    }
}

echo $dom->saveHTML((new \DOMXPath($dom))->query('/')->item(0));
```

I need to get `<nav>` and `<span>` inside of `<header>` with the `my_class` but I don't get.

As I can understand, I need to return back changed parents to DOM after setting the class to them, but how can I do that?

Comment: Do you mean like this using xpath and add the class to the children of the div? https://3v4l.org/047Iq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I've found the answer by myself:

```
...
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);

foreach($dom->getElementsByTagName('body')[0]->childNodes as $bodyChild) {

    if($bodyChild->nodeName == 'header') {

        foreach($xpath->query('.//text()', $bodyChild) as $textnode) {

            if(preg_match('/\S/', $textnode->nodeValue)) { // exclude non-characters
                $textnode->parentNode->setAttribute('class','my_class');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, you have to get the node by its name by using [getElementsByTagName](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementsbytagname.php) instead of checking by text node.

```
$pageHTML = '<html>
<head></head>
<body>

<header>
  <div>
    <nav>Menu</nav>
    <span>Another text</span>
  </div>
</header>

<section>Section</section>
<footer>Footer</footer>
</body>
</html>';

$dom = new DOMDocument;
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom->loadHTML($pageHTML);
libxml_use_internal_errors(false);

$elements = $dom->getElementsByTagName('header');
foreach ($elements as $node) {
    $nav = $node->getElementsByTagName('nav');
    $span = $node->getElementsByTagName('span');

    $nav->item(0)->setAttribute('class', 'my_class');
    $span->item(0)->setAttribute('class', 'my_class');
 }

echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

Comment: Thanks, but there may be different conditions, not only get by tag name. And I need to get the very text nodes regardless of and not knowing their parent tags. It was just an example in my question. See my own answer